# jquery.i18n cannot assign locale from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

From [this](https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/jquery-i18n-the-advanced-guide/)
documentation I understood that you can change the locale doing this:

`$.i18n().locale = 'en';`
That works fine on my code also, and will select the correct lang, what I want to do is to change this dynamically and take that value from a variable, so in order to do that I made a local storage where I keep my selected lang like so:

```
var currentlang = window.localStorage.getItem('lang');
```

And if I console.log(currentlang) that var currentlang I will see the corect lang that was saved in local storage like: "en","it" depending on the language I selected from the lang picker.

The problem is when:

```
$.i18n().locale = currentlang;
```

For some unknown reason that won't take the assigned value into consideration, from what I saw from the console:

using variable the console log will print: "it" -- won't take the lang

usign hard coded $.i18n().locale = 'it' will print : it -- this will work

I need to mention that both are string formats tho.

Comment: `$.i18n().locale = currentlang;` is likely working just fine but you are probably overwriting the locale afterwards somehow. Consider other areas where the locale might be set afterwards.

Comment: I think that's not possible cause if I just replace var currentlang with any of my langs, let's say "it", will just work fine.

Comment: Could you create working snippet to show your issue? Are you sure that default value isn't set after you assign value from localstorage?